# Hypothesis test to detect outliers without normal assumption

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have SAT scores for 10 students. The scores are listed below. The full score for math is 800, the full score for reading&writing is also 800. The last student whose student id is 10 is an outlier obviously. I would like to find a hypothesis test and p values to validate that the last student's grade is an outlier among all the 10 students. I tried some cluster methods. But they all cannot provide p value.

```
student id    Math   reading&writing
1              700      700
2              720      690
3              750      700
4              730      680
5              710      690 
6              720      670  
7              760      680
8              720      700
9              600      510      
10             320      350
```

Comment: Why is that so obviously an outlier? I would expect some students to perform poorly. (In fact, I think the grading of the SAT requires that some students always get the lowest score.)

Comment: This is just an example for demo. I would like to find a hypothesis test to detect outlier in small data set without normal assumption.

Comment: If you're looking for justification to treat #10 as an outlier, consider drawing a scatterplot of the data.  Use standardized axes (that is, scaled so that one standard deviation is the same length for both variables). That will be more insightful, too, because it will expose #9 as a possible outlier.

Comment: There's this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grubbs%27s_test_for_outliers - now you may say, this assumes normality. However, you can only define outliers properly *relative* to an assumed distributional shape; "outlier" means "incompatible with the distributional shape assumed for the data". If you allow any kind of distribution, nothing lies out, everything can be modelled. So you won't get around assuming normality, or something of the same kind.

Comment: Without some distributional assumption, what makes an outlier an outlier?

Comment: As far as I know, density based methods such as DBSCAN, knn, and localoutlierfactor do not make assumptions on the underlying distribution.